# Punctuation order using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,american]{babel}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%


\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\usepackage[bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,colorlinks=false,breaklinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,hidelinks]{hyperref}%

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Francez~\citeyearpar{Francez2017-FRAOHA-2}

Crossley and Humberstone (\citeyear{cros:the-77})

Test  \citep{balafoutas2014direct}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Test.bib file**

```
@article{Francez2017-FRAOHA-2,
    author = {Nissim Francez},
    date-added = {2021-10-23 17:14:08 +0800},
    date-modified = {2021-10-23 17:14:08 +0800},
    doi = {10.1016/j.jal.2016.12.004},
    journal = {Journal of Applied Logic},
    pages = {14--23},
    publisher = {Elsevier Bv},
    title = {On Harmony and Permuting Conversions},
    volume = {21},
    year = {2017},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jal.2016.12.004}}

@article{cros:the-77,
    author = {John N. Crossley and Lloyd Humberstone},
    date-added = {2019-08-23 15:31:35 +1000},
    date-modified = {2022-06-01 11:54:29 +0800},
    journal = {Reports on Mathematical Logic},
    pages = {11--29},
    title = {The Logic of `Actually'},
    volume = {8},
    year = {1977}}

@article{balafoutas2014direct,
  title={Book Title Field},
  author={XXX, YYY and ZZZ, AAA and BBB, CCC},
  journal={Proceedings of the XXX Academy of School},
  volume={0},
  number={1},
  pages={10-12},
  year={1978},
  publisher={Own Institution},
}
```

It produced the output as:

[image]

Please refer the marked (red circled) place, currently the output as `Actually'.''` but I need as `Actually.'''`

Comment: @daleif currently, the output produced as `Actually'.''` but I want to display as `Actually.'''`, both the single and double closing quote symbol should come after the period, sorry if my question is mess....

Comment: Also, I've modified the question, hope it was correct now...

Comment: Reference: _If a sentence ends with multiple quotes (a quote within a quote), the period is placed within all of the final quotation marks._ (https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/does-punctuation-go-inside-or-outside-quotation-marks/)

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, exactly ... thanks...

Comment: More evidence that this is the most idiotic punctuation rule ever.

Comment: Note: `biblatex` with `babel` requires `csquotes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\mkbibquote{...}` for the quotation marks in the `.bib` file

```
@article{cros:the-77,
  author  = {John N. Crossley and Lloyd Humberstone},
  journal = {Reports on Mathematical Logic},
  pages   = {11--29},
  title   = {The Logic of \mkbibquote{Actually}},
  volume  = {8},
  year    = {1977},
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, it is recommended to use `csquotes` with `biblatex` if you load `babel` or `polyglossia` (though this is no requirement and the quotation marks will still be moved even without it).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,american]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Francez2017-FRAOHA-2,
  author    = {Nissim Francez},
  doi       = {10.1016/j.jal.2016.12.004},
  journal   = {Journal of Applied Logic},
  pages     = {14--23},
  publisher = {Elsevier Bv},
  title     = {On Harmony and Permuting Conversions},
  volume    = {21},
  year      = {2017},
}
@article{cros:the-77,
  author  = {John N. Crossley and Lloyd Humberstone},
  journal = {Reports on Mathematical Logic},
  pages   = {11--29},
  title   = {The Logic of \mkbibquote{Actually}},
  volume  = {8},
  year    = {1977},
}
@article{balafoutas2014direct,
  title     = {Book Title Field},
  author    = {XXX, YYY and ZZZ, AAA and BBB, CCC},
  journal   = {Proceedings of the XXX Academy of School},
  volume    = {0},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {10-12},
  year      = {1978},
  publisher = {Own Institution},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\Textcite{Francez2017-FRAOHA-2}

\textcite{cros:the-77}

Test  \citep{balafoutas2014direct}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Crossley, John N., and Lloyd Humberstone. 1977. “The Logic of ‘Actually.’” Reports on Mathematical Logic 8:11–29.]

Comment: Sir, you're the master of `biblatex`... Thanks a lot...